# No data getting pushed from Azure stream analytics to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-stream-analytics

I have data getting pushed from Azure IoT Hub -> Stream Analytics -> CosmosDB (Core SQL API)
In stream analytics I can see the data is coming. But I am not seeing the data in cosmos db.
I have created cosmos db and container. And in Stream analytics, configured input and output. And in output, selected cosmos db and its details.

Where did I miss?

Comment: hard to say. Did you follow the official article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output

Comment: Not possible to answer this question with so little information. Please include more details, configuration, code, errors, etc.

Comment: The issue was I did not start the job. I could not see that step also in any docs. Finally in azurelab page, I could see it and worked all. https://azure-samples.github.io/azureiotlabs/CosmosDB/

Answer (score -1):

Please provide more details or open a support ticket with Azure.